# Python error when querying MySQL -- 'int' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, mysql

This code was working fine yesterday, running as a cron job.  Suddenly today, it is not and I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ac33g1r1/Documents/BD_Scripts/test plist script.py", line 28, in <module>
    [plist[sid], lastQ[0]] )
  File "C:\Python33\pymysql\cursors.py", line 117, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python33\pymysql\connections.py", line 187, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise Error(errorclass, errorvalue)
pymysql.err.Error: (<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("'int' does not support the buffer interface",))
```

I've searched and can't figure out why this has suddenly changed.  Python version is 3.3.0  on Windows Server 2008.  I'd really tlike to get this cron job working again, but don't know what is actually the cause.

Here is the code:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='1.2.3.4', port = 1234, user = 'uname',  passwd='pword', db='db_x')
cur = conn.cursor()

lastQ = [165]
plist = [3327, 2145, 3429, 3442, 2905, 3339, 2628, 1655, 1831, 3202, 2551, 2110]

###Debug statements
print("plist")
print(len(plist))
print ("\n")

print("last[Q]")
print(lastQ[0] )
print ("\n")
lastQ[0] = lastQ[0] + 1
print(lastQ[0] )

# Code that is throwing error

for sid in range(len(plist)):
   lastQ[0] = lastQ[0] + 1
   cur.execute("""INSERT INTO queuelist(itemID, sortID)
               VALUES(%s,%s)""",
               [plist[sid], lastQ[0]] )

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the similar problem on 64-bit Windows 7 and [this workaround](https://code.google.com/p/pymysql/issues/detail?id=55) helped me. Just **replace unpack_int24, unpack_int32 and unpack_int64** functions in pymysql's **connections.py** with

```
def unpack_int24(n):
    try:
        return struct.unpack('B',n[0])[0] + (struct.unpack('B', n[1])[0] << 8) +\
            (struct.unpack('B',n[2])[0] << 16)
    except TypeError:
        return n[0]+(n[1]<<8)+(n[2]<<16)

def unpack_int32(n):
    try:
        return struct.unpack('B',n[0])[0] + (struct.unpack('B', n[1])[0] << 8) +\
            (struct.unpack('B',n[2])[0] << 16) + (struct.unpack('B', n[3])[0] << 24)
    except TypeError:
        return n[0]+(n[1]<<8)+(n[2]<<16)+(n[3]<<24)

def unpack_int64(n):
    try:
        return struct.unpack('B',n[0])[0] + (struct.unpack('B', n[1])[0]<<8) +\
        (struct.unpack('B',n[2])[0] << 16) + (struct.unpack('B',n[3])[0]<<24)+\
        (struct.unpack('B',n[4])[0] << 32) + (struct.unpack('B',n[5])[0]<<40)+\
        (struct.unpack('B',n[6])[0] << 48) + (struct.unpack('B',n[7])[0]<<56)
    except TypeError:
        return n[0]+(n[1]<<8)+(n[2]<<16)+(n[3]<<24) \
              +(n[4]<<32)+(n[5]<<40)+(n[6]<<48)+(n[7]<<56)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade Python or pymysql?

I see in the pymysql issues list that there are various known issues when used with Python 3 that sound similar. Due to the distinction between byte arrays and strings in Python 3 the unpack_* functions in pymysql/connections.py aren't working correctly. See http://code.google.com/p/pymysql/issues/detail?id=55#c3 for an example issue description and a provided work-around.

Comment: If I paste in the suggested change to my script, I still get the same error.  Is this supposed to go somewhere else?

Comment: I didn't upgrade either.  It just started happening yesterday.  After months of the script working fine.  I had been running Python 3.2.3.  At the end of November I switched to another server, still running Windows Server 2008, and installed Python 3.3.0.  The same script was running fine until yesterday when the problem started occuring

Comment: The function implementations need to replace the ones already in the file provided by your mysql library (open pymysql/connections.py - probably in a subdirectory of C:\Python3.3 )

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me momentum and I finally have it working.  I was able to get it fixed by addressing two issues.  The first was as you described by editing the unpack functions as described at http://code.google.com/p/pymysql/issues/detail?id=55#c3

Comment: Here's what I changed with the old commented out

Comment: The second thing I had to doo was add a '%' sign between the end of the SQL string and the beginning of my arguments list, like this    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO itemlist (itemID, sortID)
               VALUES (%s, %s)"""    ******* added this without quotes --> " %  " ********(item[sid], lastQ[0])

Comment: The workaround was [merged](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/commit/13b0d8719e1d848f24755df20d4f2053612e2efc) in december 2011.